# How to run git status without modifying .git/index - such as in a PROMPT_COMMAND

Tags: git, bash, command-prompt, file-permissions

I've got a PROMPT_COMMAND that shows git branch information using git status, unfortunately when 'git status' is invoked, it appears to be modifying the .git/index file.

This is not good since if you are running with a user that has rights over the target directory (such as on a shared filesystem or if you're running as a privileged account) - it winds up changing the ownership of that file to your user since git appears to be recreating the .git/index file.

Is there any way to run 'git status' that will keep it from modifying the .git/index file?

Comment: Sidestepping the issue somewhat, why don't you just clone the repository instead of having multiple users sharing the same repository?

Comment: The issue is administrative users that have a git aware prompt enabled. Normally this isn't an issue - but just noticed that merely cd'ing into the other users directories (application accounts) resulted in file permission/ownership changes.

Problem tracked to 'git status' command. ref-parse doesn't show the symptom. 

Other people have similar questions related to dropbox and the index file constantly getting modified - triggering syncs - with no useful answers for this case.

Comment: Excellent reason :) The issue now is to pinpoint under what circumstances, exactly, `.git/index` is modified.

Comment: Looks like it's this in builtin/commit.c cmd_status():

`    refresh_index(&the_index, REFRESH_QUIET|REFRESH_UNMERGED, &s.pathspec, NULL, NULL);`

which unfortunately isn't wrapped in any way.

Comment: or the call to:        update_index_if_able(&the_index, &index_lock);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Git version is at least 2.15, run `git --no-optional-locks status`.  See [commit 27344d6a6c8056664966e11acf674e5da6dd7ee3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27344d6a6c8056664966e11acf674e5da6dd7ee3), which added this new option.

Otherwise, if you can make sure the index is up to date before running `git status`, `git status` won't update it again; but this is kind of tricky.  Alternatively, you could temporarily make the index read-only—but this will interfere with other `git` commands running in parallel—or you could copy the index to a temporary and run `git status` with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` set to the path name of the temporary, then remove the temporary.  This last is clumsy but will work with historical Git.

(Incidentally, I don't run `git status` from [my own hand-rolled status-constructing bash prompt code](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/Dotfiles/bashrc), though it was not specifically for this reason.  Instead, I run an explicit `git update-index`, which you could omit at the cost of performance, perhaps based on `$PWD`.)

Comment: thank you for the pointer to that option, that looks like it will work great once I get that version deployed.

Comment: Thank you!
Use option BEFORE <command>. Exampl: `/usr/bin/git --no-optional-locks show -s --format=%B $SHA`

Answer (score -2):

Running `git status` does not modify the index file.

```
$ ls -l .git/index
-rw-r--r-- 1 adelsbergerm 1049089 445386 Jul 11 15:07 .git/index

$ git status
On branch REDACTED
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/REDACTED' by 211 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   REDACTED

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ ls -l .git/index
-rw-r--r-- 1 adelsbergerm 1049089 445386 Jul 11 15:07 .git/index
```

Your claim that modifying a file would change ownership is also suspect.

I suppose you *could* have some OS nobody's heard of where reading a file automatically writes to it and writing to a file automatically claims ownership of it, but barring that it would seem these are observation errors and you need to look for the problem elsewhere.

Comment: `git status` *does* appear to touch `.git/index` under certain conditions. I checked the timestamp of `.git/index` in a repo I haven't looked at in a while before and after running `git status`, and the modified time changed from Oct 10 to the current time. (macOS 10.12.6, with `git` 2.13.6).

Comment: @chepner - I showed my work.  If you think your disagreement is worth a down-vote, it must be worth showing yours as well.  If you can outline circumstances under which `git status` writes to the index, feel free.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't know the circumstances; I just know that it *is* possible, so this isn't really helping the OP if they *also* observe a change to the index.

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia That's likely. It is a clone of the `bash` repo, so I'm sure there was probably at least one `checkout` or `pull` performed since Oct 10.

Comment: @chepner - Oh, so in other words your observation *doesn't* show that running `status` updates the index; just as I said in the answer you saw fit to downvote, it was some other factor that you mis-attributed.  And yet my pointing out the need to look elsewhere is worthy of a downvote.  Interesting.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger You demonstrated that running `git status` doesn't *always* change the file. If you can prove running `git status` *never* changes the file (which would quite a feat considering both the OP and I are *observing* it to happen under certain circumstances), I will happily retract my downvote.

Comment: @chepner - Except you *didn't* observe `status` changing the timestamp, as you admitted in the above comments.

Comment: I ran `ls -l .git/index; git status; ls -l .git/index` to observe the change in timestamp. I didn't run anything else between the calls to `ls`.

Comment: `git status` *can* re-write the index file. See [this section of builtin/commit.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/14c63a9dc093d6738454f6369a4f5663ca732cf7/builtin/commit.c#L1415-L1431) (the driver for `git status` is in the commit source!) and note that the default in [`use_optional_locks`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/14c63a9dc093d6738454f6369a4f5663ca732cf7/environment.c#L343-L346) is to *enable* updating the index.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger agreed that it doesn't _always_ change it, but it does in certain circumstances. (BTW, are you same Mark at UMR? If so, been a while!)

Comment: Excellent.  I appreciate @torek providing a *proper* rebuttal that addresses the facts in question.